# mode: 'no-cors' working with fetch but fails for axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, cors, axios

I prefer axios over fetch because of its simplicity and ease-of-use. I am running a local dev server which sends AJAX requests to some remote endpoint. The request gets blocked due to the same-origin-policy. So I modified my webpack config like this:

```
devServer: {
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
},
```

Now if I use fetch for making API requests, I add `"mode": "no-cors"` to allow cross origin requests and everything works fine. However, this does not work with axios.

Whereas fetch is based on [Request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request), which allows specifying mode: "no-cors", axios is based on XHR, which has no support for specifying mode.
I can work around the issue by opening an insecure chrome window by running `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` where `--user-data-dir` is some path of my file system. However, an insecure chrome instance won't allow extensions to run, so I can't use React and Redux DevTools. 
Here is a snippet that uses fetch and axios to make requests. The fetch call works while axios fails:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(someAPIEndpoint, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))

  axios
  .get(someAPIEndpoint, {
      mode: 'no-cors',
  })
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Using a proxy server is not possible in my situation either. Is there any other workaround in code so that i can use axios and bypass this issue. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you have access to the remote API? Can you address the issue there?

Comment: @i.brod The issue is not with the remote API. I have tested using curl already. Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header is set there. The local webpack dev server that is serving the files like index.js, app_bundle.js etc. has not set the response headers. I set it in webpack config and the problem is solved for fetch calls, but the solution doesn't work for axios as there is no way to specify mode in axios. And axios is needed as with fetch, "then" block will run even on error, so handling AJAX is a bit cumbersome. So,

Comment: To be honest i don't understand how the Webpack dev-server configuration is related to this, being that your Ajax requests are performed from your browser, but i don't much about these things, so of course i can be wrong. What i can recommend is to take the time to create some "ajax wrapper" for the Fetch api, which will throw an error for anything above the 200 range. This way, you will not need to repeat these checks across your application, and you would have an "axios-like" functionality.

Comment: @i.brod Thanks for the "AJAX wrapper" idea. Will do that. Explanation of issue - webpack dev server is serving files on localhost:3000. If the API server was running on my local system, then it was fine. But as the remote endpoint is on a different domain than the page, i.e. localhost in this case, browser blocks this due to same origin policy. This is why running an instance of chrome by disabling web security works without any config needed. But that blocks extensions too, so no react devtools. Hope I was able to explain the cause of issue

Comment: I still don't understand. I run my frontend(also a webpack dev-server) on localhost:3000, whereas my backend runs on localhost:8000, which are technically two different domains, and it all works. Regarding the wrapper: I now played a bit with Fetch, and i see it rejects calls with statuses like 400, 404, 500 , etc. Is it possible the api was changed? If so, your job of "Wrapping" the fetch api is much esier, it seems you only need to take care of the JSON conversion.

Comment: Lol sorry, i was looking at the wrong thing. Fetch does indeed resolve 404 as "success", which is a huge problem. So you'll need to work a bit more :D

Comment: "I prefer axios over fetch because of its simplicity and ease-of-use" lolz